# Can someone explain why local fulfillment action for google assistant still require a public https endpoint?

Tags: actions-on-google, home-assistant

To give a little context, this about research using Home assistant and Google Assistant integration without exposing the service to the internet, relying only on local fulfillment. I know the fulfillment URL defined in an action need to be publicly accessible and secure for the Google Assistant to transfer the intent. But in the case of a local fulfillment, and if we don't want any cloud fallback option, why couldn't we configure a local unsecure webhook ?

The workflow would be :

1. Send an action request via Google Assistant (from phone app) to the cloud
2. Google cloud send the action to the local connected google home equipment
3. That action is handled by a local fulfillment script run on the Google home device so that it can now send the intent on the local network using the local IP of the device (home assistant)
4. The local device can still communicate back to google cloud (device not exposed but still connected to the internet)

I still don't know why we don't have that option available. Maybe I don't understand the Google Assistant stack well, so I need some enlightenment.